# Some way to get colors from string in php?

Tags: php

I have a string like this

```
$color="rgb(255, 255, 0)";
```

I want to get values 255,255,0 either in an array or in three different variables. For eg

```
$arr[0]=255;
$arr[1]=255;
$arr[2]=0;
```

I think so it can be done in regular expression. But i am bad in it. Thanks

Comment: You're aware that css color expressions might also contain ratios, or be in `rgba()` format?

Comment: @mario i dont know that but actually you are right this input is actually coming from `$('#right').css('background-color')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it is always in that format then this should work without using a regular expression:

```
$color = str_replace(array('rgb(', ')', ' '), '', $color);
$arr = explode(',', $color);
```

We use `str_replace()` to strip out the uninteresting data and whitespace and then `explode()` the string on commas to give the output array format you desire in `$arr`.

I have also added this [solution to a codepad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/6Hd5Y2) so you can see what happens when you run it.

Comment: So why has this been downvoted? The code works and answers the question posed.

Answer (score 4):

With this code you don't have to worry about extra spaces between commas and numbers

```
$data = "rgb(255, 255, 0)";
$data = "rgb(     255    , 255     ,  0  )";
preg_match_all("/rgb\s*\(\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*\)/i", $data, $matches);
print("<PRE>");
var_dump($matches);
print("</PRE>");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$colors = array();
preg_match('/rgb *\( *(\d+), *(\d+), *(\d+) *\)/', $colors);
list( , $red, $green, $blue) = $colors;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$color="rgb(255, 255, 0)";
$color=explode('(',$color);
$color=explode(')',$color[1]);
$color=explode(', ',$color[0]);
echo $color[0]."<br>";
echo $color[1]."<br>";
echo $color[2]."<br>";
?>
```

See [codepad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/fZ3QCj) example.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$text =  'rgb(255, 255, 0)';
preg_match_all('/\\d+/', $text, $matches);
print_r(reset($matches));
?>
```

*edit* With the reset() function

Comment: You would need to use `reset()` or `current()` to get the correct output format.